# PHP dividing gives 0

Tags: php, math, operators, divide

I'm dividing these numbers; 16 /25 and getting 0 where I want 0.64

My code:

```
echo 16 / 25;
```

I'm getting these numbers from my .html file and just made the code simple for you.

My original code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$poolSize = (int)$_POST["poolSize"];
$turnoverTime = (int)$_POST["turnoverTime"];
$turnoverRate = (int)$_POST["turnoverRate"];

$pumpRequirement = 0;
$filterAreaRequirement = 0;


function calcPumpRequirement($poolSize, $turnoverTime){
    $pumpRequirement = round($poolSize / $turnoverTime);
    echo $pumpRequirement."<br>";
}

function calcFilterAreaRequirement($pumpRequirement, $turnoverRate){
    $filterAreaRequirement = $pumpRequirement / $turnoverRate;
    echo $filterAreaRequirement;
}

calcPumpRequirement($poolSize, $turnoverTime);
calcFilterAreaRequirement($pumpRequirement, $turnoverRate);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for my rookie mistake. Just started PHP today.

Comment: You are using round() function

Comment: not in the function `calcFitlerAreaRequirement` which is the function calculating the 16 / 25

Comment: @Detilium Maybe because `$pumpRequirement` equals 0 ?

Comment: Fix this code exaple to contain ONLY a broken part, and provide us with `var_dump`'s

Comment: @DishaV. Why remove `(int)` ? That part of the code doesn't do anything wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You set $pumpRequirement to 0. So it will always be 0. You need to set it outside function.

```
function calcPumpRequirement($poolSize, $turnoverTime){
    $pumpRequirement = round($poolSize / $turnoverTime);
    echo $pumpRequirement."<br>";
    /// return value
    return $pumpRequirement;
}

$pumpRequirement = calcPumpRequirement($poolSize, $turnoverTime);
calcFilterAreaRequirement($pumpRequirement, $turnoverRate);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of, check out manual about [Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

At the end, `echo 16/25` works well. Your problem is you expect your `$filterAreaRequirement` var being changed outside of function scope you're willing to change it.

Comment: Made it work with the `global`. Thank you. I'm sorry for my rookie mistake. Just started working with PHP today.